# Create an object with a return value

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to know if this is possible.

```
number = function(n){

  var num = n;

  this.add = function(x){
    return num + x;
  }

  return num;

}

alert(number(7)); //returns 7

seven = new number(7);
alert(seven.add(3)); // returns 10
alert(seven); // want this to return 7, but will return [object Object]
```

I don't need number(7) to return 7, but it would be nice.

Comment: You may want to know about function factory pattern: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: You want to have both a number value *and* it having properties such as `.add`?

Comment: Reminds me to pythons decorator pattern.

Comment: @pimvdb yes, exactly. Not limited to numbers either, if possible.

Comment: @user1446253: Ah OK; the answers provided will work but you won't be able to conveniently work with them in code, e.g. `seven === 7` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a "toString":

```
number = function(n){

  var num = n;

  this.add = function(x){
    return num + x;
  }

  this.toString = function() {
    return num + "";
  };

  return num;

}
```

You can also give it a "valueOf" function:

```
  this.valueOf = function() { return num; }
```

That will let you do:

```
alert(seven + 7); // 14
```

Answer (score 7):

First `return num;` has no effect in your code. The object returned by the function is `this`. If a constructor function does not return an object explicitly, it will always implicitly return `this` (see step 3 in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)).

That said, there are two methods you could override, namely, [`toString` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and [`valueOf` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
function MyNumber(n){
  this.num = n;
}

MyNumber.prototype.add = function(x){
    return this.num + x; // or `this + x` since we implemented `valueOf`
};

// Is called whenever the object has to be converted to a string
// e.g. alert(myNumber) ; myNumber + " is the answer to all questions"
MyNumber.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toString(); // or `this.num.toString()`
};

// Is called whenever the object has to be converted to a primitive value
// e.g. myNumber + 42 ; myNumber == 42
MyNumber.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.num;
};
```

The added benefit of overwriting `valueOf` is that JavaScript will call this method also internally the convert to object to a primitive value.

For example, using an instance as operand in normal addition would work too (instead of calling `.add`):

```
> var n = new MyNumber(7);
> n + 10
  17
```

---

That said, if you just want to create a wrapper for primitive types, then don't do that.

[As pimvdb mentions in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961548/javascript-create-an-object-with-a-return-value/10961587#comment14310622_10961548), strict comparison would fail (for example). That is to be expected and one of the reasons why to avoid the object versions of primitive values (`Number`, `String`, `Boolean`) (i.e. `"foo" === new String("foo")` is `false` as well). Objects simply don't behave like primitives and mixing these creates more complicated code.

Comment: return num has an effect if I am just calling it as a function though right? And no adverse effect when I don't?

Comment: Yes, if you simply call it as a function, then it would return the number you passed to it (with `return num;`). But by doing so, `add` would be assigned to the global object (`window`) so you really should not call it as a normal function.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to reuse the `Number` you'll need to return the reference to the function in the constructor:

```
var number = function(n) {

  var num = n;

  this.add = function(x){
    return num + x;
  };

  this.value = function() {
      return num;
  };
}
```

Comment: @Pointy: Not strictly true. A constructor returns `this` unless an object is explicitly returned. (It doesn't work for numbers because they're not objects, but you can return a `Number`.)

Comment: Ah OK - yes I think somewhere in my head I knew that; it's not the kind of code I would ordinarily write!

Answer (score 1):

Override `toString`:

```
number = function(n){

  var num = n;

  this.add = function(x){
    return num + x;
  };

  this.toString = function(){
    return num;
  };

  return num;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you want an object to behave as, well, an object except for when it is passed to a function? the variable `seven` in your example is an object, so there's no way it'll simply return `7` when referenced anywhere.

What's more, `num` is essentially a private variable. So using `for...in` and `JSON.stringify` trickery won't do you any good. What you should do is either make the `num` variable an object property (`this.num`) or create a member function (`this.getNum(){return num};`).

After that, you can use the property/method freely:

```
alert(seven.num);//alerts 7, but requires num to be declared as a property
alert(seven.getNum());//alerts 7, requires the method
```

I'd suggest using a method in this case, since you're obviously using this function both as a constructor and a regular function (Which, might I add, isn't a very good idea). 
On a slightly pedantic note: it is custom to capitalize the first letter of a constructor, and not to use names that might collide with JS native types (String, Number, Object, Function...)

```
function MyNumber(n)
{
    this.num = n;//as a property
    this.add = function(x)
    {
        return this.num + x;
    }
}

var seven = new MyNumber(7);
alert(seven.num);//alerts 7
```

Though, if num shouldn't be altered -I'm guessing that's the case here- an extra function is the route I'd take:

```
function MyNumber(n)
{
    var num = n;
    this.add = function(x)
    {
        return num + x;
    };
    this.getNum = function()
    {
        return num;
    };
}
alert(seven.getNum());
```

If you're still planning on using the constructor as a regular function, you're best of checking how the function/constructor was called:

```
function MyNumber(n)
{
    var num = n;
    if (!(this instanceof MyNumber))
    {//not called as constructor
        return num;//or a function, or something else (treat this as a closure)
    }
    //Same code as above goes here
}
```

I might be going a bit off topic here, but I can't help but think that you might want to read up on closures, objects and constructors in JavaScript.